# Remove page number on first page using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am using fancyhdr and this is my preamble. The first page still has `1` in the footer while other pages have `Page 2`, `Page 3` and so on. How to remove the `1` on the first page?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fontencoding{T1}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{something here}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
```

Comment: After `\begin{document}` add `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably also issuing `\maketitle`, which issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`. The `plain` page style inserts the footer only (as `\thepage`). As such, you can override this and issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` *immediately* after `\maketitle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{something here}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle% This also issues \thispagestyle{plain}, so...
\thispagestyle{empty}% ...remove headers & footers

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```